# How do I properly delete a directory only if it is empty?

Tags: .net, windows, directory, filesystems

I would like to delete a directory if and only if it contains no files.

I'm currently checking for 0 file system entries within the directory then deleting right away, but that leaves an edge case that I would like to avoid. Something like locking the directory seems to be the way. Most filesystems probably don't offer this feature, but maybe there is some workaround?

Comment: Are you considering folders as files?

Comment: @hoombar: Yes, anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`Directory.Delete(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3.aspx) it will throw an [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) when your specified directory is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

if directory is not empty Directory.Delete doesn't deletes it and throws IOException

Comment: I read the MSDN documentation two times and I still missed it. You're right.